# How make the Zoom level appropriately as per my picture for MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mkmapview, mapkit

In my app, I'm using `MKMapView` I want to zoom as per my picture I tried `MKMakeCoordinate` with various values randomly but didn't received the exact result. Please help to issue this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> // delta is the zoom factor // 2 will zoom out x2 // .5 will zoom in
>   by x2

```
-(void)zoomMap:(MKMapView*)mapView byDelta:(float) delta 
{

    MKCoordinateRegion region = mapView.region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = mapView.region.span;
    span.latitudeDelta*=delta;
    span.longitudeDelta*=delta;
    region.span=span;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```